# How to store xml somewhere on server to avoid communication with server on each request made by user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am using Adlib api's to fetch data in XML format. I have decided to use LINQ to XML so that I can query the xml easily for the value of the elements that I need. But I don't want to send a new request each time when a user's search session is going on. Instead I am not able to find a way to store my xml somewhere in session state or application state or "somewhere" so that I can then use that xml for a particular session of the user.

The above condition is valid if a user is searching a keyword and I am then getting a bunch of results in xml format.

How should I deal with the storage of xml to avoid talking with server for each request!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the session state, which will be active for the current user's session eg

`Session["AdlibXmlData"] = your xml data`

Then you can access `Session["AdlibXmlData"]` elsewhere in your site.

Comment: I have tried using it. Right hand side is the xmldocument and left hand side is the session. I am doing this: ' Session["coll"] = CRecordSet;' and when I take the value of session in a label it only shows "System.Xml.XmlDocument"

Comment: Ahh, sorry I meant to be a bit more clear. You need to store the XML text only in the session (i.e. XmlDocument.ToString(), or however you get the XML text from XmlDocument). Then, when you need the XML again, get the XML text from `Session["AdlibXmlData"]` and load it into an XmlDocument object. You need to keep the data in the Session small if you can.

Comment: I have tried doing tostring() but it doesn't help. the label shows the same value System.Xml.XmlDocument

Comment: You need to use either `InnerText` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.innertext.aspx or `InnerXml` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.innerxml.aspx To get the actual XML.